# how often should i be indexing?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

i asked the question of whether an index would help me:

[should i be creating an index for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961834/should-i-be-creating-an-index-for-this)

i understand that since i am adding code every time in this procedure, i would need to re-index. in this case is it even worth it to index every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to re-index. Once you create an index it mysql, the engine automatically preserves that index. It updates it whenever the content of the table changes.